# Merging two ResourceManager objects in Silverlight

Tags: string, resource-files

I have multiple SilverLight apps that share a common silverlight dll. I have different string resource files in common and in every project. Is there a way to merge multiple ResourceManager objects in to one, so that I can use only one resource instead of referencing multiple.

`var commonMsgs = new ResourceManager("Nabeel.Common.Messages", GetType().Assembly);`

`var appMsgs = new ResourceManager("Nabeel.MyApp.Messages", GetType().Assembly);`

I want something like a new object that contain values from both the above messages.

`var allMsgs = commonMsgs + appMsgs;`